# Collect Data from User Task - How can I reference this collected data in another workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I start a Collect Data from User Task in a primary list workflow.

After the task is completed, I would like to access the values that were collected from within another custom workflow.

Here's the scenario:

[image]

Here's the image of the error I get saying it doesn't guarantee a single value.  I understand the logic that there could be multiple Collect Data tasks of the same type associated with the same list item, but I don't know a better/another way to accomplish this.  Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collect data action creates a task in the task list and outputs the task ID as the variable in the workflow action (Output to variable: collect). Use this ID variable to look up to the task list to find the item and get the data you need.

Comment: The problem is that I'm referencing it from another workflow on my primary task list and it says it isn't a unique lookup and therefore only the first value will be returned.  The lookup I'm using is against the ID of my primary list to the Task list "Workflow Item ID" field. Is there a better way?

Comment: I'm confused by the setup, can you expand the process a bit in your question?

Comment: oh i get it now, use that task id instead. sorry i didn't ready your answer correctly/fully.

Comment: no problem, remember that in any SPD workflow where you create a task, collect data, and even create an item, that variable for that action is the corresponding task or list item id that you can then use in your next actions to fetch the outcome or user response.